# Variable to Text

Tags: r

Let's say I have a variable "chicago" which is currently 30.

```
chicago <- 30
```

I also have a text string variable "a" which is currently "chicago".

```
   a <- "chicago"
```

How can I store another number (say 40) to "a" and make it save to chicago.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `assign` function:

```
chicago = 30
a = "chicago"

assign(a, 40) 
chicago
# 40
```